# What is the difference between 'je ... desto ...' and 'je ... umso ...'?

Tags: difference

Today, I've said something like

> Je größer x ist, desto kleiner ist y.

A fellow student asked me what the difference is to

> Je größer x ist, umso kleiner ist y.

Could you answer that question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning of *„je … desto“* and *„je … umso“.*

According to *[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/je_desto_umso_nachdem#Bedeutung1),* both expressions relate two comparatives:

> je früher du kommst, desto mehr Zeit haben wir
>
> je eher, desto besser
>
> je intensiver er an dem Roman arbeitete, desto geringer wurde der Einfluss Gustav Bugenhagens

> je länger er unterwegs war, umso besser gefiel ihm das Land
>
> je älter er wird, umso bescheidener wird er
>
> je weiter südlich und je weiter die durchzuführende Schwenkung, umso weiter war der Weg

Furthermore, there is the rare and antiquated expression *„je … je“*.

> je länger, je lieber
>
> er kann ja nicht dafür, dass die CDU ihn je mehr fürchtet, je unglaublicher seine Geniestreiche werden

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately nowadays, you can do a lot in German according to Duden provided you find enough fellow speakers joining in...

"Je" goes with "desto" describing a certain relationship between two elements which can attain a range of values:

> Je höher der Berg, desto kälter wird es.
>
> Je schneller ich laufe, desto früher bin ich im Ziel.

Meaning: On top of a mountain 13.000 feet high, we have -2°C, but on top of a mountain twice as high, we have -10, and so on. If I run 7 km/h, I'll finish the race at 11 a.m., if I run 15 km/h, I'll arrive at 9.29, and so on.

"Umso", on the other hand, stands alone. It literally means "by this amount" and initiates a consecutive clause setting apart two elements by a certain value:

> Gestern habe ich 10.000 Euro im Lotto gewonnen, umso schneller kann ich meinen Kredit abzahlen.
>
> Er raucht und hat Übergewicht. Außerdem macht er keine Bewegung. Umso größer ist sein Risiko zu erkranken.

And, referring to the example above:

> Er hatte sich diesmal mehr Zeit genommen, das Land kennenzulernen. Umso besser gefiel es ihm.

Meaning: I have won a certain sum of money in the lottery, and this amount of money will allow me to pay off my mortgage sooner. Before that, this wasn't possible.  Let alone he smokes and is overweight, he refuses to get some exercise, increasing his risk to get ill. The amount of time added to the time he usually spent for travelling around the country brought about his liking it even more.

Comment: The last example is terrific! +1

Comment: Gut erklärt! Klingt etwas konstruiert mit dem *umso* am Satzanfang, aber so wird es am besten deutlich. Üblicherweise würde man es an späterer Stelle unterbringen, etwa "Diesmal gefiel es ihm umso besser."

Comment: ""Umso", on the other hand, stands alone." This is a bit misleading. Umso can stand alone but it doesn't have to since it can be used as "je ... umso".

Comment: I am very sure that the "je ... umso ..." structure is possible. This answers seems to apply that it doesn't?

Comment: "Je höher der Berg, desto kälter wird es." - das ist ja nun Quatsch!

Comment: This answer has almost nothing to do with the question by the OP which is about a specific grammatical construction that has two variants: *je ... desto*, and *je ... umso*. Whether *desto* or *umso* can, or cannot, stand on its own is completely unrelated to the question.